# Django models: Why do I get "IntegrityError UNIQUE constraint failed" when I save the model twice?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    value_to_pay = MoneyField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=14, null=False, blank=False, default=Money(0, DEFAULT_CURRENCY))
    status = models.CharField(_('bill status'), max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default=UNPAID)

    def set_status_to_paid(self):
        self.status = PAID
        return self.save()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.status == PAID and self.value_to_pay <= 0: self.set_status_to_paid()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It's seeing on `save` if the value to be paid is 0 in which case it sets the bill to "Paid". However if I create a bill with value_to_pay=0 I get `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: bill.id`. I found out that I don't get this error if I remove the `save` from the `set_status`  function

```
    def set_status_to_paid(self):
        self.status = PAID
        # return self.save()
```

Why does saving twice cause this error?

Comment: Don't know if you showed the whole class, but the same error occurred for me twice already and I could solve it the one time with fixing my custom manager which accidentally filtered out the newly saved object and the other time by resetting the database sequences (manage.py sqlsequencereset).

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the branch in question closely, you will see that super.save() is called twice for that particular condition, causing objects with same id being inserted twice. Hence the integrity error as the id/pk(primary key) is unique

```
-> if not self.status == PAID and self.value_to_pay <= 0: self.set_status_to_paid() # condition is True
-> self.status = PAID
-> return self.save()
-> if not self.status == PAID and self.value_to_pay <= 0: self.set_status_to_paid() # condition is False
-> super().save(*args, **kwargs) # from return.save()
-> super().save(*args, **kwargs) # from original call
```

Comment: But wouldnt that 1) create another record or 2) update the existing one?

Comment: To create a new record, set self.id = None before return self.save, else the save will use id of old object

Answer (score 0):

your code will trigger the save twice since it will call the set_status_to_paid function then save function and inside the save function it will call again set_status_to_paid, try this instead

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    value_to_pay = MoneyField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=14, null=False, blank=False, default=Money(0, DEFAULT_CURRENCY))
    status = models.CharField(_('bill status'), max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default=UNPAID)

    def set_status_to_paid(self):
        if not self.status == PAID and self.value_to_pay <= 0:
            self.status = PAID
            self.save()
```

Comment: There is no circular call in the original code, and from the comments from the author, it is clear that they want to save 2 objects, one with status as PAID and the original object.

Comment: well it may not be since there is a qualifier (not self.status == PAID) but it show  set_status_to_paid will call save function then inside the save function again  thats why it call it twice